# Aligning multiple things under a limit

Tags: math-mode, substack

I'm using `\lim_{\substack{n\to\infty\\t_n\to t}}` to put two things under a limit.

But ideally I'd like the arrows to be directly underneath each other.

**Can this be done?**

(Something on the lines of using `&` in `\begin{align} \end{align}`).

Comment: You could use an whole `aligned` environment  as subscript to the `\lim` macro, but the spacings are not really nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\substack` is based on `subarray` which can be modified as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subxarray}{%
  \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil
    $\m@th\scriptstyle##$&$\m@th\scriptstyle{}##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{\begin{subxarray}n&\to\infty\\t_n&\to t\end{subxarray}} X_{n}(t_n).
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\scriptscriptstyle#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{\alignShortunderstack{n\to&\infty\\t_n\to&t}} X_n(t_n)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By modifying the preamble to include

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\scriptstyle#1}
\makeatother
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
```

the interstack gap is reduced from 3pt to 2pt and the limit is set in `\scriptstyle`:

[image]